# Camera ScreenToWorldPoint return biased value When it set output texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are two cameras, the only difference is one set output to a renderImage.

Camera1 calculation wrong result with ScreenToWorldPoint ---In other words, there is an error on the coordinate transformation

[image]

Camera2 is correct with ScreenToWorldPoint.

[image]

This is a problem I encounter on the job, I built a camera completely copy of the original. Just didn't set the output.

Believe me, after this operation, the result is correct, at least from the visual effect.

Why set up the output will have an impact on the coordinate transformation. The position of the camera and other attributes are no different.

Answer (score 2):

When you set a targetTexture, the texture is the screen. The size of the texture will affect the calulation of screen position.

You may use ViewportToWorldPoint instead, because a viewport coordinate is always from (0,0) to (1,1)

```
var viewPoint1 = camera1.ScreenToViewportPoint(mousePosition);
var worldPoint2 = camera2.ViewportToWorldPoint(viewPoint1);
```